# View class maintain variables from controller request

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm loading the main view within the controller `home` as following:

```
class Home
{
    public static function login()
    {
        Views::load('frontend/index', ['view' => 'account/login', 'name' => 'Stackoverflow']);
    }
}
```

Now as you can see the view being loaded is `frontend/index` but I also say what is the view that must be loaded afterwards `account/login`.

So in the `frontend/index.php` file I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php Views::load($view); ?>
        <?php echo $name; // prints 'stackoverflow' ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

What happens is that I'm able to access the variable `$name` in the `frontend/index` file but not in the `account/login` file.

The `account/login.php` file contains:

```
<h2>Hello: <?php echo $name; // shows error saying 'Undefined variable: name' ?></h2>
```

The error just tells me that the variable is not being cached/stored.

Finally my view class has the following structure:

```
<?php 
class Views 
{   
    public static function load($file, $data = null)
    {
        if(file_exists(VIEWS_PATH . $file . '.php') == FALSE)
            throw new Exception('View not found');

        if($data != null)
            extract($data, EXTR_SKIP);

        ob_start();

        require_once(VIEWS_PATH . $file . '.php');

        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        // prints the view
        echo $content;
    }
}
```

---

What can I do in order to allow the variables sent by controller to be cached/stored and called in multiple views?

Comment: That's a template, not a view.